# Privledged Instruction Error, trying to write Sequential Search in Assembly

Tags: assembly, x86

Getting a strange error after adding some array checking features to my sequential search program. After some reading it seems that this typically happens because of a corrupt stack or bad data, but checking my memory registers the data seems to disagree with that. Any ideas?

```
    INCLUDE Irvine32.inc                    ; Irvine's assembly library
ExitProcess PROTO,dwExitCode:DWORD      ; MS Windows ExitProcess function

.data
array1 DWORD 10,20,30,40,50,60,70,80,90,100 ;Test array, change as you see fit.
string BYTE "Choose Number, Press Enter When Ready: ", 0 
.code
main PROC                               ; main procedure, entry point
    mov ESI, OFFSET array1              ;move array to ESI for output
    mov ECX, LENGTHOF array1            ;set up loop for outputting array
L1:
    mov EAX, [ESI]                      ;move number from ESI to EAX
    add ESI, 4                          ;Have ESI point to next number
    call WriteDec                       ;Output EAX
    call Crlf
loop L1
    call Crlf
    mov EDX,OFFSET string
    call WriteString                    ;outputs instruction string
    call ReadInt                        ;recieves desired number from user, to EAX
    call search                         ;call search procedure
    call Crlf
    call WaitMsg

    INVOKE ExitProcess,0                ; end the program
main ENDP

search PROC
    push ECX
    push ESI
    push EAX
    push EDX

    mov ESI, OFFSET array1              ;move array to ESI for output
    mov ECX, LENGTHOF array1
L1:
    cmp EAX, [ESI]                      ;compare user input to array index
    JNE L2                              ;if not equal, jump to L2 to INC ESI
    mov EAX, LENGTHOF array1            ;for computing array position
    sub EAX, ECX                        ;This will give current position
    call WriteInt
    call Crlf
    L2:
        cmp ECX, 0                      ;determine if every element has been checked
        JLE L3
      add ESI,4                         ;Make ESI point to next register
        L3:
            string1 BYTE "Integer not found" ;If ECX = 0, everything checked
            mov  EDX,OFFSET string1          ;means its not found, so output not found
            call WriteString
            call Crlf
loop L1

    pop EDX
    pop EAX
    pop ESI
    pop ECX
search ENDP
END
```

Just to clear some things up, call Crfl, WriteXXX, ReadInt and WaitMsg are all from the Irvine32 library which come from my text book. They move the cursor, output to console window, input from window and declare a system pause respectively. WriteDec requires the EAX register and WriteString requires EDX. ReadInt puts the input into EAX. If you want more information please let me know and I'll PM you the full list of functions.

Link to project, with libraries included: https://drive.google.com/open?id=18hwuVu8oJSyDZJtblwEZfjArChVbfhkL

Comment: At `L3` you put a string in the middle of the code. Don't do that. Also, learn to use a debugger.

Comment: Also `search` doesn't end (`PROC` + `ENDP` are just decorations/syntax-sugar for MASM, they don't produce any code, so after your `pop ecx` the CPU will continue further into memory executing whatever it will find there as instructions.